# What is the difference between * and x

Tags: calculator

For PC calculators you use `*` instead of `x`, or `/` instead of `÷`. Why were these two symbols chosen over the other two?

In the standard Windows calculator, even the button uses "/" instead of "÷"

Comment: Because `x` is often the name of a variable, so using `*` for multiplication prevents confusion, and we don't want to introduce new keys to have a new key, $\times$, when we already have `*`. Similar with `/`.

Comment: @Atruro I run calc.exe and I can't create variables.

Comment: It doesn't matter; the point is that in early computer programming, `x` was a character, not a mathematical operator, and it's a character that is too easy to confuse with the mathematical symbol $\times$. You want a symbol which is easy to differentiate (for debugging purposes) and unambiguous, so the closely related `*` was chosen to denote multiplication. Neither $\times$ nor $\div$ were standard keys in standard typewriters, which made them difficult to add to early computing (typewriters used `x`). It keeps going from there. Do you have a $\div$ key on your keyboard? I don't.

Comment: @Arturo I thought it may have an interesting mathematical reason but it's just the boring old restrictions of ascii

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know which came first in this case, but I'd have to believe it came from using $\cdot$ for multiplication in writing and $/$ came from the fraction symbol.

Comment: I'd have to comment...

Comment: @The Chaz: But I can't for lack of stupid rep!

Comment: @Theo: Do you have a website or links to any projects you've worked on? (I understand if you prefer privacy)

Comment: @The Chaz: I wouldn't use my real name if privacy was my concern here. Googling my name should bring up my [old and neglected homepage](http://xwww.uni-math.gwdg.de/theo/) in Göttingen with some texts I wrote some time ago. But be aware that I'm neither [this guy](http://www.tattoo-theo.ch/Sites/artists.htm) nor [that guy](http://www.wilabonn.de/642_343.htm?h104#). Currently I'm at [ETH Zürich](http://www.math.ethz.ch/u/theo).